# ClickOnce error Configuration system failed to initialize Unrecognized configuration section startup

Tags: clickonce

I'm trying to install an application deployed with ClickOnce and I'm getting the following error

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18034
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18034 built by: FX45RTMGDR
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.17929 built by: FX45RTMREL
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
Deployment url          : http://localhost:82/My.application

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of http://localhost:82/My.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Configuration system failed to initialize
    + Unrecognized configuration section startup. (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\dfsvc.exe.Config line 2)
```

When I install it locally it works fine, but on the server I get that error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the config item on line 2 of your config file?

Comment: <configuration> <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="false"> <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku="client" /> </startup> </configuration>

Answer (score 0):

searching for a similar error brought me here - I fixed it by using the .net repair tool

Comment: Welcome to SO and thank you for posting an answer. Please consider adding an additional explanation to your your answer.